# Can the adjectivized nouns have a plural form?

Tags: plural-forms

Good day! Explain it to me please:)

Is is right to say:

*Five-storey**s** houses*

or

*Five-storey houses?*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One plural is enough. "five-storey houses"

Comment: Let me see if I have an answer in one of my pants pockets.

Comment: BTW, I would not know how to explain you. :) The word after the verb explain without any prepositions is often considered as its object. A more correct sentence to say would be "Explain it to me please." Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike some other languages such as French, English adjectives (and adjective nouns) don't ['agree'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Agreement) with the nouns they describe. Only

> five-storey houses

is correct.

Comment: You might edit to explicitly point out (she's a learner, after all) that there aren't any plural adjective forms in English, so adjectivized nouns don't have a plural form either.

Comment: What is "arms" in "arms control"?

Comment: That is the exception which proves the rule. English is full of them, unfortunately. But, well noted!

Comment: Yes: The word "storey" (US: story) cannot be an adjective, nor has it been "adjectivized". If we add a y to fruit, we have adjectivized the noun "fruit". As Khan writes, "storied" is an adjectivized noun. When we use a noun to modify another noun, it's an attributive noun or a noun adjunct.